# Bundle Vue project into single js file that can be embedded in Ghost blog post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ghost-blog

I have a simple Vue.js project built after running `yarn build`. The `dist` folder contains files like below;

[image]

I want to bundle all the files (HTML, js, CSS) into a single js file that can be embedded into a ghost blog post.

Here is an example of how this was done for a ghost blog post.

https://blog.openbloc.com/including-a-js-app-in-a-ghost-post/

My question is how do I bundle my Vue.js project files into a single file that can be deployed in a ghost blog post?

Is webpack the right tool to use? I am open to other alternatives.

I am using @vue/cli 5.0.1, yarn v1.22.17

Comment: I solved it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78026012/316700

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Creating a single JS file output

To configure Vue CLI to output a single `.js` file:

1. Disable CSS extraction with [`css.extract=false`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract).
2. Disable Webpack's chunk-splitting with [`configureWebpack.optimization.splitChunks=false`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationsplitchunks).

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ⋮
  css: {
    extract: false, 1️⃣
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false, 2️⃣
    },
  },
})
```

The build then produces a `dist` directory containing these files:

```sh
dist/js/app.bd71ae48.js      # all app code, including template, scripts, and styles
dist/js/app.bd71ae48.js.map  # source map for development (optional)
dist/favicon.ico             # favicon shown in browser   (optional)
dist/index.html              # initial index              (optional)
```

### Usage in Ghost

1. In your blog page, insert a [custom HTML block](https://ghost.org/help/using-the-editor/#adding-custom-html).

[image]

2. In the HTML block, add a `div` with an ID that matches the mounting point in `src/main.js` from your app's original source (the default ID is `"app"`).

   ```html
   <div id="app">Vue app loading...</div>
   ```
3. Add a `<script>` that pulls in the `app.js` file previously built. For example, if you've hosted the script on GitHub, you could use a CDN link like this:

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tony19-sandbox/vue-cli-single-js-file@master/dist/js/app.bd71ae48.js"></script>
   ```
4. I noticed the app's Vue icon and heading are incorrectly aligned (likely due to inherited Ghost styles), so compensate by adding a `<style>` to the HTML block that re-centers them.

   ```html
   <style>
   /* compensate for Ghost styles overriding the app's alignment */
   #app {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
   }
   </style>
   ```

The result looks like this:

[image]

[GitHub](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-cli-single-js-file)

[Ghost page](https://acme-publishing-2.ghost.io/my-vue-app/)

Comment: Really sweet. I used a more complicated solution, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899394/how-to-include-vue-app-inside-another-vue-app/61902381#61902381) (in short, using `build --target-lib --inline-vue --inline-css`). Thanks for this.

Comment: @tony19, I asked a similar question but it is for React.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440923/bundle-react-js-project-into-single-js-file-that-can-be-embedded-in-ghost-blog-p/

Comment: @tony19, I asked a similar question but this time, it is about bundling the vue.js files into a single HTML file so that it can be posted in Blogger blogspot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509127/bundle-vue-project-into-a-single-html-file-that-can-be-embedded-into-a-single-bl

Answer (score 1):

The vue cli have a command for this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library

You need to pass this command `--target lib` to the `vue-cli-service build`. This means that you only want one final file.

Also, you can pass another attributes, like:

- `--inline-vue`, that will include the Vue in your bundle, what is recommended, based on your use case;
- `--name`, the name of you bundle file;
- and in the end of the command, the entry point for you application, that is the `src/Vue.js` by default, but can be the `main.js`, for example. You have to test based on how you built your app;

So, you can try one of these combinations:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib
vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue
vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name myApp
vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name myApp src/main.js
```